# Upgrading CentOS kernel without internet connection

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, rpm

I need to update my CentOS 6.8 VM's kenrel to a more recent version.  I have tried downloading the individual parts of the kernel, i.e kernel.....rpm, kernel-firmware....rpm.  Using `rpm -ivh kernel....rpm` But I always get dependency error.  Anyone know how I can upgrade the kernel? Do I have to make a repo with all the seperate packages and yum update it?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=941

Comment: Thanks that is helpful, but I don't have any CentOS VMs with access to the internet to create the initial repo.  I have been able to download an ISO file on a windows box and make a repo with that, but it doesnt have the most recent version of the kernel.  Do you know if there is a way to download the packages from the mirror on a windows box?

Comment: There's a Windows program named http://www.httrack.com/ that you can use to mirror the repositories.

Comment: Thanks I ended up just downloading the patches I needed manually and creating a local repository from them, seemed like less work than the alternatives